# Can I run angular's method in chrome console?

Tags: angularjs

I was wonder if I can run anguar method in chrome console,because the method in angular was not a globel object,I don't know how to access to it.
eg:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
  $scope.say = function(){
      alert('hello,world.')
  }
})
```

See, I want to access the `$scope.say()` , any idea?

it's the same as below ?

```
 var fn = function(){
        function test(){
            alert('123')
        }
        return {
            abc: test
        }
    }
    fn().abc();   // 123
    fn().test();  // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, right click on an element that is inside the controller, then click `inspect element`. After that, open the console and run

```
angular.element($0).scope().say()
```

Comment: It works,can I make access to other controller's method?

Comment: As long as you can find an element that is within the controller, you can.